# National flags != [dutch-national-flag]; [dutch-national-flag] name and definition?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

- [**Dutch-national-flag (DNF) problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) refers not to the actual flag, but to variants of quicksort algorithm that must be robust to repeated elements, using a three-way partitioning function.

  - SO has a [dutch-national-flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dutch-national-flag) with [9 tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dutch-national-flag), and currently no excerpt.
  - Also there are [58 questions with the plaintext "Dutch national flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dutch+national+flag) about the sorting algorithm.
- Meanwhile, as to **actual national flags**, there are [11 questions on "national flag" -dutch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22national+flag%22+-dutch+is%3Aq), about drawing, images, HTML, emoji etc. Just noting a slight possibility of confusion. No change required on that.
- [DNF](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf) also commonly refers to Dandified YUM, the Linux package manager (@Mureinik notes).

Questions:

1. Should [dutch-national-flag] be renamed [dutch-national-flag-algorithm]/ [dutch-national-flag-problem]/ [dutch-national-flag-sort]?
2. The tag currently has no wiki or excerpt, it needs one.

Comment: Also, let's keep [dnf](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf) out of the mix

Comment: Don't touch my flag ...

Comment: Those acronyms...for me the first programming-related meaning that comes to mind is [Disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Comment: Yeah, that's the usual CTP. (CTP stands for "Confusing TLA Problem" (TLA stands for "Three Letter Acronyms")).

Comment: There's also, apparently, an [American Flag Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_flag_sort) algorithm.

Comment: I'd simply remove the 9 tags from questions and let it wither.  IMO, the tag provides no benefit to SO; people are not going to search for that tag.  It should go.

Comment: Well... Feel free to write up an excerpt, I'd say. The first sentence of your question would probably do, while it's a bit short.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an algorithm but rather [an aspect in sorting algorithms' design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) (making them robust to repeated elements).

So [dutch-national-flag-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dutch-national-flag-problem) seems like the canonical form, with [dutch-national-flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dutch-national-flag) and [dnf-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnf-problem) as possible synonyms.

Comment: Right, but a lot of the hits refer to [Dutch national flag algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dutch+national+flag+algorithm)

Comment: The acronym DNF would be misleading for the confusion noted above with DNF, the Linux package manager

Comment: @smci Googling shows no such thing as "Dutch national flag algorithm". Colloquially, it seems to be used as a shorthand for "a DNF problem solution".

Comment: @smci I would rather confuse DNF with Disjunctive Normal Form, but I agree that "dnf-problem" can be misinterpreted.

Comment: @smci ...or can it? If I type "dnf", not aliases but canonical tags will be in the popup -- so there'll be no confusion about the resulting tag's meaning.

Comment: I said "the acronym DNF" not "the term DNF algorithm". Googling for the acronym DNF gives Fedora, Dandified YUM, rpm etc. To most Linux users, that's what DNF means, not sorting. So, DNF as a keyword or in a title would be ambiguous. [dnf-...] in a tag is a different matter.

Comment: @smci how ambiguous the acronym is is irrelevant. If the user types it, they will see what tags SO has to offer on this combination of letters. It's just like Google automagically searching synonyms.

Comment: No, DNF near-universally refers to the Linux package manager, so Google traffic will be about it. It would be stupid to serve up irrelevant results on SO.

Answer (score 2):

If it indeed only occurs in the context of sorting, and the term is not used when the same data characteristics are input to other algorithms on sequences, then it should be renamed to [dutch-national-flag-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dutch-national-flag-sort).  Because this contains the original as a prefix, users will have no trouble finding it.  They'll have no trouble recognizing that it is applicable.  And unfamiliar users (such as myself) will immediately be clued into the fact that this involves a sorting algorithm, therefore perfectly on topic.

Having a good tag wiki in addition would be superb, but let's not shove off into the wiki excerpt what can be elegantly handled in the tag name itself.

Stijn is correct that a rename isn't *necessary*, but there's no downside, only gain, which makes it a good idea.